# How to use Drupal Commerce to extract all the people who purchased a specific product?

Tags: commerce, log-messages

I want to create a report (a list) of all the people who purchased a specific product.

I want to use this list for a report to verify purchase when people pickup registration packs etc., so that I can confirm those people when they arrive.

How do I get this in a report format that I can extract from [Drupal Commerce](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you mean with "reports on line items" or "a line item report" (consider refining what actually this means). But since the question is tagged with the [reporting](/questions/tagged/reporting) tag, maybe you may want to consider the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.

It would probably take a bit of time to achieve perfection, but you'd have all of Forena's xHTML-power available to finetune the ultimate result (report), for things such as:

- look-and-feel (styling/theming).
- maybe add some charts to it also (using selected data about commerce).
- saving the ultimate output (report) in formats such as PDF, DOC, etc.
- creating eMail campaigns about selected records.
- pulling in information stored in other databases related to this report.

For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://www.forenasolutions.org) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link /reports/help.
  - **Forena samples** - use the link 'Reporting samples' or visit relative link /reports/samples (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).

The newest 7.x-4.x version also includes an amazing (I think) UI for either creating your reports (the WYSIWYG report editor) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the Query Builder).

Here is some more info about the **other databases** in mentioned above:

1. Using a **SQLite** instead of MySQL database: the Forena samples actually get shipped including a (Tiny) SQLite database. Go check it out in the [demo site](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/samples): the data shown there are data contained in the sampledb, which is in SQLite format.
2. Forena comes with a full suite of [Supported database connections](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363#dbconnections) ... such as MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle, Postgress or any PDO compliant variation.

Enough reasons for considering giving Forena a try? While doing so, use it's issue queue for any type of support/docu requests you may have.

**Be aware**: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.

Comment: I'm basically trying to extract current orders with who bought them so I can get a list of names for these orders

Comment: So you are using "Drupal Commerce" with Drupal version 7, right? Are you also using Commerce Reports (cfr https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_reports)? Consider rephrasing your original question details, by including links to the modules you're using.

Comment: updated question, I want to extract all the people who purchased a specific product.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the comments in my previous reply (which I believe is still an option to consider), I'd assume that using [Commerce Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_reports) should help a lot for creating that list.

Let's hope [Matt](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/13179/matt-glaman) (maintainer of it) will step in soon to find the (maybe out-of-the-box?) answer ... It'd be interesting to hear from him also to what extend my forena-alternative might make sense also (even if it was only to enhance Commeerce reporting with all sorts of Forena-features ...).